# If neither $L_1$ nor $L_2$ are context free then is $L_1 \cup L_2$ also not a context free language?

Tags: formal-languages, regular-languages, context-free

If two regular languages $L_1$ and $L_2$ are both **not** context free languages then is $L_1 \cup L_2$ also **not** a context free?

I am aware that if $L_1$ and $L_2$ are context free languages then the language $L_1 \cap L_2$ is also context free but cannot quite connect the dots. If someone could help out that would be great.

Comment: This is a dump of an exercise problem, not a question. If you have a specific question regarding the wording of the problem or concrete steps in your own attempts at solving the problem, feel free to edit accordingly and we can reopen the question. See also [here](http://meta.cs.stackexchange.com/a/470/) for our homework policy, and [here](http://meta.cs.stackexchange.com/questions/594) for a relevant discussion. You may also want to check out our [reference questions](http://meta.cs.stackexchange.com/q/599/). What have you tried?  Have you tried working out a few examples?

Comment: Also, the question has probably been answered before. There are quite obvious counter-examples. **Important:** CFL is *not* closed against intersection!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

First, note that CFL is not closed under intersection, contrary to what you've mentioned.
For example:
$$ L_1 = \{a^ib^ic^j|i,j \geq 0\}, \quad L_2 = \{a^ib^jc^j|i,j\geq 0\}. $$
We see that $L_1 \cap L_2 = \{a^ib^ic^i|i\geq0\}$,
which is not CFL.

For your question,
Take two languages $L_1, L_2$ which are not CFL.
Let
$$
\begin{align*}
L'_1 &= \{0x|x \in L_1 \} \cup \{1x|x \in \Sigma^*\}, \\
L'_2 &= \{1x|x \in L_2 \} \cup \{0x|x \in \Sigma^*\}, \\
\end{align*}
$$
which are both not CFL. It's easy to see that $L'_1 \cup L'_2 = \Sigma^*$, which is CFL (as it is a regular language).

Comment: Please consider not to encourage [undesirable posting behaviour](http://meta.cs.stackexchange.com/questions/594).